# Docker ARG missing from CMD (17.06.0-ce)

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile, I define ARG values and use them successfully in RUN commands.

However, in my CMD the ARG value does not appear.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8
MAINTAINER xxx@yyy.com 

ARG NAME=UNSET

CMD echo NAME is $NAME
```

Example:

```
12:29:27 ~/workspaces/k8s/docker > docker build scratch
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8
 ---> f68f6cb88633
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER xxx@yyy.com
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b974feaede6a
Step 3/4 : ARG NAME=UNSET
 ---> Running in 0d1ebf746c33
 ---> c58708f2a58c
Removing intermediate container 0d1ebf746c33
Step 4/4 : CMD echo NAME is $NAME
 ---> Running in 52952d8c9e0d
 ---> be9dca528d15
Removing intermediate container 52952d8c9e0d
Successfully built be9dca528d15
12:29:33 ~/workspaces/k8s/docker > docker run be9dca528d15
NAME is
```

I'd expect that line to be `NAME is UNSET`, or whatever value I specify (using `docker build --build-arg NAME=whatever`).

Comment: Docker history gives a clue:

    sha256:be9dca528d15942328bc7b062754920845e3312c40d2176d4d1184754f477cac   10 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "echo NAME is $NAME"]

So I'm left with "which incantation does what I want"?

Comment: But I've yet to find a variant where my arg makes it into the CMD.

Comment: I've abandoned this approach; I'm now generating the Dockerfile itself from a template.